# Delphi wrongly says 'Comparision always evaluates to False' on repeat ... until loop type

Tags: delphi, loops, repeat

I will put a piece of code, a function.

The code works perfectly, no forever loop.

It is the compiler warning system what is getting me mad.

On compiler warnings it say there is a loop that will never ever end, since its condition "allways evaluate to False" and that is totally wrong, the condition can be True and if runned it goes inside the loop and ends.

Right i can ignore such warning message, but i wish it won't be shown... i know it is a BUG on compiler warnings system, is there any FIX?

This is the piece of code (read comments to know why i write it as that):

```
function DoSomethingRetrying(ReTries:Byte=3):Boolean;
var
   HasSucceeded:Boolean;
begin // Do something till not fail, retrying no more than a given number of times
     HasSucceeded:=False; // Initial value to indicate it has not yet succeeded
     repeat // Enter into the ReTry loop till not fail or had tried more than a given number of times
           Dec(ReTries); // Reduces the number of retries to ensure that the loop will end when done more than a given number of times.
           try // Just to caught some kind of error
              // Here can go a tipical AssigFile sentence
              try // Just to caught some kind of error
                 // Here can go a tipical Reset sentence
                 // Here can go a tipical Read sentence
                 try // Just to caught some kind of error
                    // Here can go some ':=' sentences to move data form the record to variables, maths, etc
                    HasSucceeded:=True; // Set the condition so the loop will end immediately.
                 except // Something went wrong
                       // Here you can put some code in case needed
                 end;
              finally // Just in case something is mandatory to be done, if failed or not.
                     // Here can go a tipical CloseFile sentence
              end;
           except // Something went wrong
                 Sleep(1); // Just make a little pause between retries
                 HasSucceeded:=DoSomethingRetrying(ReTries); // ReTry it again (with counter one less)
           end;
     until HasSucceeded or (0>ReTries); // Repeat the loop till no fail or done a max number of retries
     DoSomethingRetrying:=HasSucceeded; // Return if has succeeded
end;
```

Just add the code (as it is, without any modification) to any unit on implementation section... then compile it... warning will bring up with text:
`W1021 Comparison always evaluates to False`

If you analize the code you will see:

1. It puts `False` onto `HasSucceeded` variable
2. Enter inside the `repeat...until` loop
3. Decrements `ReTries` variable, so it is one less than passed (it can be negative)
4. Inside some `try` blocks it puts `True` onto `HasSucceeded` variable
5. As it is, it will never ever run the `Sleep(1)` part; that part is for cases where most 
   external `try` goes to the `except` part, for example if there where an `AssignFile` that fails (file does not exists, etc)
6. It will evaluate the `until` condition, `HasSucceeded` variable has the value `True` and also can be true the `(0>ReTries)` part (for example when `ReTries` has a negative value)
7. It exit the `repeat...until` loop
8. The function will return `HasSucceeded` value (in this case `True`)

But no need to see deeply inside the code... imagine i call it with one of theese sentences:
`DoSomethingRetrying(0);`
`DoSomethingRetrying(-1);`

In that cases the `until` condition part `(0>ReTries)` will be `True`.

How dare can the compiler tell `HasSucceeded or (0>ReTries)` is allways evaluated to False?

Also more, run the code (step by step if you preffer) and you will see it ends, so condition can be evatualed to `True`, it is not allways `False`... compiler warning message lies!!!

So, i was wondering how can i work-around it without deactivating such warning message type?

Thanks in advance!

P.D.: At least it happens on turbo Delphi 2006 (not yet tested with others).

Comment: Your question has been answered, and let me echo the view that you should always suspect yourself before the compiler. Of course, the compiler does sometimes get warnings wrong. My main point is that when faced with such a situation, you should simplify. 95% of the code above is spurious. Always simplify the code to the smallest variant that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 14):

Your `ReTries` variable has type `Byte`, which is an unsigned type. Since it's unsigned, its value is always greater than or equal to zero. Thus, the comparison `0 > Retries` is indeed always false. Your assertion in step 3 that the value can be negative is wrong, and so the compiler is correct to warn you.

Before you seek to disable a compiler hint or warning, make *absolutely* sure the compiler is actually wrong.

Comment: Well found Rob. So just to add the obvious, change ":byte=3" to ":ShortInt=3" and the warning is gone.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot.

Sorry to correct you... as i said i do not want at all to dissable the compiler warning message... instead i want to "edit" the code so that warning do not appear... Just changing Type 'Byte' to 'Integer' does the trick.

Any way, when i put code (for example an Assign to a non existent file) the function works also well, tell it has failed and return False, why? it is supposed to fail since you tell me Byte type can not be negative, but when i run it i see Byte type variable can hold -1, why?

Anyway i change Byte to Integer, solved and more clear.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think it is just because it is really compiling code as if it where a Shortint type, not Byte.
I do a step by step with a call `DoSomethingRetrying(-1);` and value is `-1` with Byte type, why? it is supposed that compiler must say such call is an error, since `-1`is not a valid value for `Byte`type, but not, it compiles and run perfectly (at least on my Turbo Delphi 2006) tested on Lazarus and compiler say it is an Error and do not compile. Again, Thanks at lot.

Comment: Perhaps you have range checking disabled.

Answer (score 2):

not a bug at all: compiler is correct to issue a warning

> In that cases the until condition part (0>ReTries) will be True.

You will never be correct because ReTries is of type Byte :)

> HasSucceeded:=True;

could never happen if Dec(ReTries); raises an exception :)

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot.

But i have a question... when i put FileAccess and file does not exists it ends telling Not Succeeded.

I just change Type to Integer and warning disappear, Thanks for sugestion!!!